# Use exact version numbers in package.json or not?

Tags: node.js, npm

Common practice for version numbers of npm dependencies in package.json has been to enter exact version numbers (like `1.2.4`) instead of inexact version numbers (like `^1.2.4` which allows installing bug fix releases like `1.2.5`) to make sure a future installation will not break due to changes in dependencies (see for example [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-tips-to-become-a-better-node-developer/)).

Using exact version numbers has a drawback in that you can't automatically update bug fix versions of dependencies. This is an issue when it's nested dependencies having security fixes or bug fixes. For example, at this moment the package `karma-browserstack-launcher` uses `browserstack`, which is using an outdated version of `https-proxy-agent` containing a security vulnerability. This becomes very visible right now thanks to `npm audit` which looks for security issues in dependencies.

Since some time we have `package-lock.json`, which is used to lock down the version numbers of all dependencies. This may change the way we deal exact or inexact version numbers in `package.json`.

My question is: given `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, what is the best strategy nowadays to deal with version numbers of dependencies? Use exact versions or not? How can I deal with security issues in nested dependencies if they don't get upgraded?

Answer (score 2):

My feeling is that

- packages that are libraries and meant to be used to others should have inexact version numbers and should specify the minimum they require in order to work; and
- top-level projects that aren't going to be included elsewhere should specify the full version numbers of their requirements, so they can have the most control over when things are updated.